# France: how to calculate total tax burden (including social security)

Tags: france, taxes, social-security

Say I got a job in France with a salary of 43,000 euro per year, and I am a citizen of another EU country.

What will my total tax burden be?

I know I can calculate my income tax using a table like that found [here](http://leparticulier.lefigaro.fr/jcms/p1_1621350/le-bareme-de-l-impot-sur-le-revenu-pour-2017?cid=c_113075).

However, I know I also must pay social security (per the rates [here?](https://www.french-property.com/guides/france/finance-taxation/taxation/social-security/social-welfare-levy/)). However this appears to be partially tax-deductible.

I'm struggling to come up with a clear calculation of how much tax + social security I will have to pay in total on this salary?

Also, are there any other taxes or tax-like payments that I am missing here? E.g. will I also need to pay for health insurance?

Thanks!

Comment: This would seem to be a question about French taxes rather than anything to do with expatriates. Not a bad question, but one any French citizen would likewise be interested in knowing.

Comment: @outflak While you're right about any French citizen being interested by this, I find a lot of expats (including myself!) asking this question. Given that it's in English, I think it's useful to keep here for expats who may not understand the sometimes complicated French sites.

Comment: And to answer, you can find a few things by googling 'france tax simulator' and the closest I found was one by HSBC, but none of them aligned at all with the actual amount of tax I paid this year. So I can't really give you an answer, because I don't have a good one yet.

Comment: I also disagree with the close vote. Tax etc. rates could have exemptions or different rates for non-citizens and/or temporary residents. Plus an expat may not understand the native language or even if he or she does, will have to handle specialized vocabulary.

Comment: @mkennedy yup. As an expat in France for 2 years who still doesn't understand the taxes, because I'm not a French scholar and can't understand the overly complicated documentation, I seriously disagree with this close vote. I can think of at least 5 expats who I know personally who would be interested in seeing this question answered, properly, in English.